# Cucumber (with watir-webdriver): undefined method `confirmation_token'

Tags: email, cucumber, watir-webdriver, confirmation, specifications

How cann I use confirmation token in cucumber? I need this to test a registration without to check an e-mail.

My code:

```
  @b.text_field(:name => 'profile[prename]').set 'Kurt'

  @b.text_field(:name => 'profile[surname]').set 'Russell'

  @b.text_field(:id => 'profile_email').set 'user@trash-mail.com'

  @b.text_field(:id => 'profile_password').set 'password'

  @b.text_field(:name => 'profile[password_confirmation]').set 'password'

  @b.button(:id => 'profile_submit').click

  @ctoken = Profile.last.confirmation_token

  @b.goto("http://localhost:3000/profiles/confirmation?confirmation_token=#{@ctoken}")
```

or:

```
  @b.goto("http://localhost:3000/profiles/confirmation?confirmation_token=#{Profile.last.confirmation_token}")
```

I become: undefined method `confirmation_token' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that `Profile.last` returns `nil` in your case, hence the error message `undefined method confirmation_token for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`. Please share code where you define `Profile`.

Comment: How can I find this confirmation_token path?

Comment: I have not idea what that is. What is `Profile`? How is it defined?